# Response header GAE endpoints

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to take control over creating response in Google App Engine's Endpoints?

I know that GAE [can inject Request object](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types#injected_types) to some API method

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Google Cloud Endpoints officially support that. But one thing you can try to do is to extends com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet class, and make some customization there. And then change your servletclass in the web.xml file into the one you created.

I personally never try to do that, so I cannot guarantee that will work.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for answering. Maybe my question sounds bit complicated than it is. Actually I need just add some custom headers to  response. Will try your approach.